# How to draw a rectange on top of JPanel?

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d, rectangles

I want to draw a rectange on top of `JPanel`. Next I want to set proper location for this rectangle. This is how I do this. 
I tried to change number in `g.fillRect(margin, margin, 30, 30)`, but my rectangle is always located in the center of `JPanel`. Why?

```
JPanel chartPanel = new JPanel();

// here we add components to chartPanel
// ...

chartPanel.add(new LegoBox());

class LegoBox extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int margin = 0;          
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(margin, margin, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to calc the margin , so the rectangle is centered?

Comment: @oliholz: I want to control the position of a rectangle. For instance, how to put it 10 pixels left from the top left corner of JPanel?

Comment: Perhaps the `new LegoBox()` is centered in your `chartPanel`

Comment: I just do this chartPanel.add(new LegoBox()); Why does this command put my rectangle into the center?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is the `LayoutManager` from `chartPanel` ?
 
For reproducing your problem you have to post a working example.
Try filling the `chartPanel` with you custom panel:

```
chartPanel.setLayoutManager(new BorderLayout());
chartPanel.add(new LegoBox(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

---

paintComponent:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
g.setColor(Color.red);
int rectWidth = 30;
int rectHeight = 30; 
int marginLeft = 12; // a pixel value
int marginTop = 17;      
g.fillRect(marginLeft, marginTop, rectWidth, rectHeight);
```

Comment: Is there some more flexible way to define the location of rectangle? For instance, based on pixels?

Comment: after the `LegoBox` has the full width, you can easy set your margin to a pixel value.